# laravel 10 starter template breeze and reactjs inertia problem

Tags: breeze, laravel-10

I am using laravel 10 and I have the node latest version. I want to use breeze starter template and react inertia. but after installation when I start the application and npm run dev. it's returning me this error. the image attested.

I have try updating npm, composer and other dependency. but result is 0.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aptIj.png)